# Error when run jekyll server on windows 7

Tags: ruby, server, jekyll

I'm trying run `Jekyll` server in my local machine, so when I run `jekyll server` in terminal, returning fallowing message:

```
$ jekyll serve
Configuration file: C:/xxx/Site/_config.yml
            Source: C:/xxx/Site
       Destination: C:/xxx/Site/_site
      Generating...
c:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/posix-spawn-0.3.11/lib/posix/spawn.rb:164: warning: cannot close fd before spawn
'which' não é reconhecido como um comando interno
ou externo, um programa operável ou um arquivo em lotes.

  Liquid Exception: No such file or directory - python c:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/pygments.rb-0.6.0/lib/pygments/mentos.py in _posts/2015-06-02-welcome-to-j
ekyll.markdown
                    done.
  Please add the following to your Gemfile to avoid polling for changes:
    gem 'wdm', '>= 0.1.0' if Gem.win_platform?
 Auto-regeneration: enabled for 'C:/xxx/Site'
Configuration file: C:/xxx/Site/_config.yml
    Server address: http://127.0.0.1:4000/
  Server running... press ctrl-c to stop.
```

Cause I trying enter http://127.0.0.1:4000/, is not happen, no error, no 404, only a empty page.

Where is problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python does not appear to be installed, which is why you get a liquid exception when trying to use the code highlighter Pygments.

According to [this tutorial](http://jekyll-windows.juthilo.com/3-syntax-highlighting/), which is the suggested tutorial written by Julian Thilo on the [Jekyll documentation](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/windows/), you need `Python 2.7.x` at time of writing. Here is a summary of what you need to do to get the Jekyll install and server up and running.

**Step 1 : Get Python**

Download the latest version of Python 2.7: [here](https://www.python.org/downloads/)

**Note:** Make sure to add python.exe to Path and select “Entire feature will be installed on local hard drive. **This is needed on Windows** or else Jekyll will fail to build the website when trying to highlight code with Pygments.

**Step 2: Install Pip**

It's a Python package manager which you'll use to install Pygments. [follow the official documentation for doing this.](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing.html)

**Step 3: Get Pygments**

Finally, Open up a command line and type in `python -m pip install Pygments`

**Step 4 : Done**

Run `jekyll serve` again.

**Optional Step**

Since Pygments is the default syntax highlighter, you don't have to explicitly define what highlighter you're using, but if you prefer to, add this line to your `_config.yml` file: `highlighter : pygments`

**ALTERNATIVE 1: Don't want highlighters**

If you won't be using a code highlighter just edit the markdown post you have `2015-06-02-welcome-to-jekyll.markdown` and remove the Liquid tags like so:

`{% highlight ruby %}`

```
  //Ruby code on the template you can ignore
```

`{% endhighlight %}`

**ALTERNATIVE 2: Rouge, no need for Python**

Rouge is a Ruby code highlighter, which while does not require Python and all that dependencies as it is written completely in Ruby (which you already have because Jekyll runs on Ruby). You'll need to edit the `_config.yml` to use `rouge` like so: `highlighter : rouge`, and run `gem install rouge` in the command line, as mentioned in same tutorial. *Note that at time of writing Rouge has [lesser language support compared to Pygments](https://github.com/jneen/rouge/wiki/List-of-supported-languages-and-lexers).* (but still a whole lot)

Here's another tutorial on [setting up Jekyll](http://yizeng.me/2013/05/10/setup-jekyll-on-windows/) on Windows. And it would be a good idea to follow the [excellent tutorial](http://jekyll-windows.juthilo.com/) I've previously linked for installing Jekyll on Windows.